# Eloquent unique() method need to return last item

Tags: mysql, collections, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using the Eloquent `unique()` collections method to return the unique item. It does return the first unique item from the collections. However, I require returning the last unique item from the collections.

```
$collection = collect([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]);
                      ~~~   ~~~

$unique = $collection->unique();

$unique->values()->all()
```

The above code will return the `// [1, 2, 3, 4]`. As you can see, the [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-unique) method returning the first `1` and `2`, not the last `1` and `2`.

I can also use a callback with the `unique()` method. However, I'm getting nowhere how the algorithm should work to return the last unique item from the collections.

Comment: I am confused what you said "returning the first 1 and 2, not the last 1 and 2". It returns `[1,2,3,4]` so what do you mean by last `1` and `2`? If you require last items then you can read last items in array.

Comment: Consider you've two items in a collection like this. `[1, 1]`. Now, if you use the `unique()` collections method it will return `1`. However, which `1` would return? The `1` from the beginning of the collections and I want the `1` from the end of the collections.

Comment: Does it matter? It is same right? Unique means unique.

Comment: Sometimes it does matter when you've other elements on your collections and you need to return the last unique item. However, no problem. I've figured it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out myself. This answer is for those who's having the same issue like me:

```
$diary = Diary::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->unique('workId')->values()->all();

return $diary;
```

In the above, I've used the `orderBy()` method to change the order of the collections. `get()` method will return the result as the collections. `unique()` method is used to return only unique items from the collections. `values()` method returns a new collection with the keys reset to consecutive integers and the `all()` method return the complete collections.